# Selenium form submission: additional pictures upload fails

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

We are currently working on a project, that has a lot of content, that needs to be uploaded. I've decided to automate this process through selenium+python script. And there are some issues when I try to upload pictures. With the help of script I pass pictures paths into input fields, form than shows preview of pictures, I hit submit button.

The form looks like this, it is built with Lavarel (Backpack Admin Panel), and it is built not by me.

**Form Screenshot**

[image]

The first image (the one named preview) is usually loaded without issues, but other (named additional) have mainly two kinds of failure:

1. Upload fails:

When I do it through geckodriver, form submits successfully, but if I check if they are uploaded - they are absent. When I do it with chromedriver, after hitting submit button chrome "loads/waits for response" in infinity, while script console seemingly waits as well without any exceptions.

One way to fight this type of failure was the additional compression of pictures. Some preview pictures were not even uploaded fully with the grey parts left, and it's when decided to try compressing them.

Question do drivers have some limit for uploads or does Lavarel back-end see that I'm not human and limits upload volume? Because when I do it manually, everything works fine.

2. Upload overrides:

The second issue is much more complicated. Basically, the application has "days" instances which consist of "tasks", and each task has a preview pic and additional pics. The issue basically is that somehow additional pictures from the latest task submitted automatically override pictures in the same positions of earlier uploaded. I know that it is probably more back-end concern, but if you by any means have some theories I'd greatly appreciate them.

My request here is to provide any theories on this variant of issue.

Code of geckodriver script:

```
from numpy import NaN
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import os


### Загрузка excel документа
df = pd.read_excel(os.getcwd()+"/program.xlsx", sheet_name="Лист1",header=None)

task_count = df.iat[3,0]
series = df.iat[3,1]
theme = str(df.iat[3,2])
age = df.iat[3,4]
theme_descr = df.iat[1,2]
date= str(df.iat[3,3])


### Функция перевода текста в html разметку для wysiwyg-редактора
def task_formatter(string):
    if "*" in string:
        final_string=""
        final_string=final_string+string[:string.find("*")-1].replace("\n","<br>")+"<ul>"
        string = string[string.find("*"):]
        while "*" in string:
            final_string+= string[:string.find("\n")+1].replace("*","<li>").replace("\n","</li>")
            string =string[string.find("\n")+1:]
            
            if "\n" not in string and "*" in string:
                final_string+=string.replace("*","<li>")+"</li></ul>"
                string=""
            if "*" not in string and string != "":
                final_string+="</ul><br>"+string
                string=""
        final_string+="</p>"
    else:
        final_string="<p>"+string.replace("\n","<br>")+"<p>"
    return final_string


### Проверка файла
def check_file():
    no_problem = True
    try:
        f = open(os.getcwd()+"/pdf/prog.pdf")
    except:
        print("prog.pdf отсуствует")
        no_problem = False
    try:
        f = open(os.getcwd()+"/pdf/print.pdf")
    except:
        print("print.pdf отсуствует")
        no_problem = False
    try:
        f = open(os.getcwd()+"/img/cover.jpg")
    except:
        print("cover.jpg отсуствует")
        no_problem = False
    
    if no_problem: print("Обожка и файлы под загрузку на месте") 
    else: print("Есть ошибки")


    for col in range(0,3):
        for row in range(6, 6+task_count-1):
            a=df.iat[row,col]
            if str(a)=="nan":
                print("Есть пустая ячейка (ряд: "+str(row+1)+", колонка: "+str(col+1)+") продолжать? [y/n]")
                no_problem = False
    
    for col in range(5,7):
        for row in range(6, 6+task_count-1):
            a=df.iat[row,col]
            if str(a)=="nan":
                print("Есть пустая ячейка (ряд: "+str(row+1)+", колонка: "+str(col+1)+") продолжать? [y/n]")
                no_problem = False
                    
    
    if no_problem: print("Пустых ячеек нет") 
    else: print("Есть ошибки")

    for row in range(6, 6+task_count-1):
        task_number = df.iat[row, 0]
        pic_number = df.iat[row, 7] 
        if pic_number > 1:
            for i in range(1,pic_number+1):
                try: 
                    f=open(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+"."+str(i)+".jpg")
                    print(str(task_number)+"."+str(i)+".jpg")
                except: 
                    print("Нет картинки: "+str(task_number)+"."+str(i)+".jpg")
                    no_problem = False
        elif pic_number == 0:
            print("Картинка не нужна, зеленая задача")
        else: 
            try: 
                f=open(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+".jpg")
                print(str(task_number)+".jpg")
            except: 
                print("Нет картинки: "+str(task_number)+".jpg")
                no_problem = False
    

    return no_problem

### Вход на сайт
def site_start():
    driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/admin/")
    if "Увійти" in driver.title:
        elem=driver.find_element(By.ID,"email")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("***")
        elem=driver.find_element(By.ID,"password")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("***")
        sleep(1)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Вход не требуется")

### Создание списка задач
task_names = []


def create_series():
    driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/public/admin/seria")
    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='search']")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys(series)
    is_not_loaded = True
    series_already_created = False
    while is_not_loaded:
        sleep(0.5)
        try: 
            elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "dataTables_empty")
            is_not_loaded = False

        except:
            sleep(0.5)
            try:
                elem = elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "odd")
                series_already_created = True
                is_not_loaded = False
            except:
                print("Ждем загрузки серии")

    if series_already_created is not True:
        driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/public/admin/seria/create")
        elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "name")
        elem.send_keys(series)
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-selection").click()
        sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/span/span/span[2]/ul/li["+str(age)+"]").click()
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "SEO").click()
        elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "meta_title")
        elem.send_keys(series)
        elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-success")
        elem.click()

    



### Создание программы
def create_program():
    driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/public/admin/program/create")

    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"name")
    elem.send_keys(theme)
    
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-selection").click()
    sleep(1)
    elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-search__field")
    elem.send_keys(series)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"pdf")
    elem.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/pdf/prog.pdf")
    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"pdf2")
    elem.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/pdf/print.pdf")
    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@accept='image/*']")
    elem.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/img/cover.jpg")

    #Вставка даты, в разработке
    #driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Календар").click()
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='tab_kalendar']//button").click()
    #elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='tab_kalendar']//input[@type='date']")
    #elem.click()
    #elem.send_keys(date)


    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,source_text).click()
    sleep(0.3)
    elem=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"cke_source")
    #elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='tab_osnovne']//div[@cke_description]//textarea")
    elem.click()
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys(task_formatter(theme_descr))
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"SEO").click()
    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"meta_description")
    elem.send_keys(theme_descr[0:500])
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"btn-success").click()



### Создание задач
def fill_tasks(s_task,e_task):
    start_row=6
    e_task+=start_row
    s_task+=start_row-1   
    for row in range(s_task,e_task):
        task_fill_in_process = True
        while task_fill_in_process:
            try:
                num_col=0
                name_col=1
                text_col=2
                rec_col=4
                time_col=5
                img_col=6
                img_count_col=7

                task_name = df.iat[row,name_col]
                task_text= df.iat[row,text_col]
                task_number = df.iat[row,num_col]
                task_is_green = False
                task_expand = False

                if "Підготовка" in str(task_number): task_is_green = True


                task_rec=str(df.iat[row,rec_col])
                if task_rec == "nan": task_rec="" 

                task_time=""

                if df.iat[row,time_col] != "00:00":
                    task_time=str(df.iat[row,time_col]).replace(":","")

                task_search_name = " ".join((series,theme,str(task_number),task_name))

                task_names.append(task_search_name)

                if df.iat[row,img_col] == "+": task_expand = True
                task_img_count = df.iat[row,img_count_col]
                has_multiple_image = False
                if task_img_count >1:
                    has_multiple_image = True
                    task_img_count+=1

                driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/admin/task/create")

                sleep(1)

                elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"name")
                elem.send_keys(task_search_name)
                elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"title")
                elem.send_keys(task_name)
                if task_time != "":
                    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"time")
                elem.click()
                sleep(0.3)
                elem.send_keys(task_time)
                sleep(1)
                driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, source_text).click()
                sleep(0.3)
                elem=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"cke_source")
                elem.click()
                elem.clear()
                elem.send_keys(task_formatter(task_text))

                driver.switch_to.default_content()
                elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"info")
                elem.send_keys(str(task_rec))
                
                sleep(10)

                if task_is_green:
                    print("Green")
                    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Розбити завдання").click()
                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='cke_93']").click()
                    sleep(0.3)
                    elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//textarea[@title='"+source_text_field+"']")
                    elem.click()
                    elem.clear()
                    elem.send_keys(task_formatter(task_text))

                
                else:
                    print(str(row))
                    sleep(0.3)
                    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Зображення").click()

                    sleep(0.3)
                    if has_multiple_image:
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='btn-group']/div/input").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+".1.jpg")
                        for i in range(1, task_img_count):
                            sleep(0.3)
                            if i !=1: driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"add-repeatable-element-button").click()
                            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-row-number='"+str(i)+"']/div/div/div/input").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+"."+str(i)+".jpg")
                    else:
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='btn-group']/div/input").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+".jpg")
                        sleep(0.3)
                        if task_expand:
                            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-row-number='1']/div/div/div/input").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/img/"+str(task_number)+".jpg")
                    sleep(0.3)

                

                task_fill_in_process=False

            except:
                print("Ошибка, повторить заполнение задачи? [y/n]")
                if input()=="n":
                    task_fill_in_process=False
                else:
                    task_fill_in_process=True


            driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"btn-success").click()

### Привязка задач
def assign_tasks():

    task_names=[]

    for row in range(0,task_count):
        row=row+6
        num_col=0
        name_col=1

        task_name = df.iat[row,name_col]
        task_number = df.iat[row,num_col]

        task_search_name = " ".join((series,theme,str(task_number),task_name))

        task_names.append(task_search_name)

    sleep(1)
    driver.get("http://system.mr-leader.com/admin/program/")

    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@type='search']")
    elem.send_keys(theme)  
    sleep(2)

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Редагувати").click()
    except:
        print("Не находит ссылку на редактирование программы, растяните окно и нажмите enter")
        input()
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Редагувати").click()


    sleep(3)

    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Завдання").click()
    row_number=1
    for row in task_names:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"add-repeatable-element-button").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-row-number='"+str(row_number)+"']/div[2]/span/span[1]/span").click()
        elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"select2-search__field")
        row_number+=1
        elem.click()
        elem.send_keys(row)
        loading=True
        time_wait=0
        while loading:
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "loading-results")
                sleep(0.5)
                time_wait+=0.5
                print(time_wait)
            except:
                loading=False
                sleep(0.5)
                print("Loading ended")
                elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"select2-search__field")
        
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        
        sleep(1)
    
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"btn-success").click()



if check_file():
    print("Проверка прошла успешно, начать скрипт? [y/n]")
    if input()=="y":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"/drivers/chromedriver")
        source_text="Джерело"
        source_text_field="Текстовий редактор, col1"
        site_start()

        print("Введите 'ru' или 'ukr':")
        if input()=="ru":
            source_text="Источник"
            source_text_field="Визуальный текстовый редактор, col1"

        create_series()
        create_program()
        fill_tasks(1, task_count)
        #print(task_names)
        assign_tasks()
```

Comment: your program is too difficult to understant and to read, i suggest you to  do a little program to upload one image and check if present..

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, it appears to be a mistake on the backend part. Images were not given unique names which resulted in rewriting previously uploaded ones.